# AWS Java SDK (Apache HTTP Client) on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, apache-httpclient-4.x

Our application is heavy AWS Java SDK dependent and we want to migrate it to GAE.

AWS Java SDK doesn't work on GAE because it is using Apache HTTP Client.

Around 4 years ago there were attempts to port AWS Java SDK to GAE:

- https://github.com/apcj/aws-sdk-for-java-on-gae (1)
- https://github.com/radomirml/aws-sdk-for-gaej (2)

Or Apache HTTP Client to GAE:

- http ://esxx.blogspot.ru/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html (3)

All of them are very much out of date or not available anymore.

My question is: what would be modern and wise approach to make AWS Java SDK GAE-frendly?

I can see this opportunities:

1. Fork aws-java-sdk and replace Apache HTTP Client with URLFetchService as in (1) and (2)
2. Try to write custom ClientConnectionManager and ManagedClientConnection classes or something like this for Apache HTTP Client as in (3).
3. Wrap all of AWS Java SDK into REST services (sic!) and deploy it to GCE.
4. Somehow use SDK for another language from Java, maybe JavaScript/Python?